# Magento 2: How to set item Row total?

Tags: magento2, cart, totals, quoteitem

I want to set a custom row total.
I am using 'checkout_cart_product_add_after' event.
And want to update Row total.
I going to add an extra amount in an item row total.
like,

```
$item->setRowTotal($item->getRowTotal + 100);
$item->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkout_cart_product_add_after` is triggered after the quote has already been saved.

Try `sales_quote_product_add_after`

The event has one parameter, `items` with an array of quote items that have been generated from this product. For simple products it is always one item. For complex products (bundle, configurable), the first array item is always the parent (i.e. the main product). So you get your item like this:

```
$item = $observer->getItems()[0];
```

Comment: Not working.....

Comment: @RaviSoni, any luck ?

Comment: Yes, We have set our custom price divided by qty in Add action and then set that price in the registry. Then in the observer, we get that registry and then set a custom price logic. But yes, still we get point difference in price.